# how to fire databse query in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how to i fire this query in laravel 5.2 please give me answer

"SELECT count(keyword) abc,keyword FROM `exclude_keywords` GROUP BY keyword order by abc"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i was find my won question answer in laravel documentation

DB::table('keywords')->select(DB::raw('count(keyword) as abc, keyword')) ->groupBy('keyword')->orderBy('abc', 'desc')->get();

Comment: Do read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) thoroughly (RTFM!), it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way

```
DB::select(DB::raw(SELECT * FROM table_name));

//In your case

DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT count(keyword) abc,keyword FROM exclude_keywords GROUP BY keyword order by abc"));
```